# MacOS X 向けプログラミングの参考書

Tags: objective-c, macos

MacOS X 向きの普通の GUI プログラムを作りたいと思っています。

当方 Windows や昔の MacOS (漢字Talkとかの時代です) での GUI プログラムの開発経験はありますが。 MacOS X に関しては単なるユーザーです。

MacOS X でのプログラムを勉強するのにおすすめの本や、サイトを教えて下さい。
なお、iOS については今のところ手を出す予定はありません。

チュートリアル形式で、ある程度まとまったプログラムを作れる形式だと嬉しいです。

日本語の資料が望ましいですが、良質の物ならば英語でも構いません。
( 例えば　Rails　における　Ruby on Rails Tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/ のようなもの )
又、特別高価でなければ、有料でも構いません。

Answer (score 4):

## OSXアプリ開発に必要な知識

基本的にOSXのアプリケーション開発に関して必要な知識としては

- SwiftやObjective-Cなどのプログラミング言語の知識
- Cocoaフレームワークの知識
- Xcodeなどの開発環境に関するに関する知識

があるとは思います。

ここからは、各項目についておすすめの書籍を紹介しておきます。(僕自身まだ、手にしてはいない書籍も何冊がかありますが。)

## 最新の情報について

はじめに言っておきますが、現在のXcode6.1に関して最新の情報が乗る書籍は、おそらく少ない or 存在しないと思いますので、そのあたりは、Appleのドキュメントを参照するのが一番早いでしょう。

というか、Appleの公式のドキュメントは見ておくべきです。

## SwiftかObjective-Cについて

僕は今なら、Swiftを学んだ方が良いと思います。なぜなら、

- 既にSwiftの情報が十分に出ている
- SwiftとObjective-Cと比較すると、Swiftの方が記述が短かくなりやすく、学習しやすい。
- たぶん、Objective-Cが無くなっていくだろう?

ということだと僕は思いますので、この回答ではSwiftの書籍を紹介します。

## iOS開発を学ぶ

先の回答にもありますが、基本的にiOS開発をまずやられることを、おすすめします。ここに関しては、特にコメントしません。追記するとすれば、

- Core Dataなど、OSXの方がよりノンコーディングに開発できる。

という感じがします。

## 全体的な入門

「**詳細! Swift iPhoneアプリ開発 入門ノート Swift 1.1+Xcode 6.1+iOS 8.1対応**」がおすすめです。

http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0%EF%BC%81Swift-iPhone%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA-%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88-Swift-Xcode-ebook/dp/B00QT1VE2W/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1418799331&sr=8-2&keywords=Swift+%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80

基本的に、iOSの書籍ですが、基本的なXcodeやSwiftの書き方などは書いてあるかなと思います。ざっと、眺めた感じですが。

## Swiftの書籍

「**詳解 Objective-C**」で有名な萩原氏が、最近出した、「**詳解 Swift**」が良いでしょう。というか、たぶんObjective-Cや、Swiftのリファレンスはこの人の本さえあれば良いと思います。

## Cocoaフレームワークについて

まず始めに言っておきます。ここは、特に

**最新情報が乗っている、まとまった書籍なんて無いです!!!!!**

一応、先の回答にもありましたが、アーロン ヒレガス氏が書いた、「**MAC OS X COCOAプログラミング 第4版**」がありますが、Xcode4.6の時代の書籍であり、内容が時代遅れ感がありますね。なので、最新情報に関しては、Appleの公式または、ブログ記事を参照した方が良いでしょう。

ただし、基本的な事項は乗っているとは思いますので、そのためでしたら読んでみるのも価値があるとは思います。

## Xcodeについての書籍

ここらも、まず前提として、Appleのドキュメントが一番良いというのは言うまでも無いのですが、Xcode5の書籍であれば、「**Xcode5徹底解説 for iOS/OSX**」がおすすめです。

基本的に、Xcode5から、基本的には開発環境自体の機能はあまり変わってないので、この一冊+Appleのドキュメントで十分だと思います。

## ReactiveCocoaのついて

また、最近は**FRP**の流れもあってか、**ReactiveCocoa**などもありますが、もしCocoaアプリケーションに慣れてきたら、ざっと記事を見ておくと良いでしょう。ただ、ReactiveCocoaに関する書籍は、たぶんありません。

Answer (score 2):

まずは、apple公式のチュートリアルを。

[Your First Mac App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/Introduction.html)

書籍になりますが、Aaron Hillegass氏の[Cocoa Programming for OS X]という本は分かりやすいと思います。英語も比較的容易ですし、各章ごとにcocoaの様々な機能を紹介しながらサンプルプログラムを作る形式なのでとっつきにくいということはありません。
日本語版もありますが、少々古かったりするので最近のAppKitまわりの更新に追いついていないかもしれません(これは日本語のmac開発関係の書籍全般に言えますが……)。

http://www.amazon.co.jp/s/ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1?ie=UTF8&field-author=Aaron+Hillegass&search-alias=books-us&text=Aaron+Hillegass&sort=relevancerank

ただ、「objective-cとは何ぞや?」というレベルだと厳しいのでその場合は、objective-cの解説書から入った方が良いかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

回り道だという印象もあるとは思うのですが，iOSの開発を少しかじると良いと思います．
理由は

- 基本的なライブラリの多くが共通である: UI 周りを除いた Foundation Framework や画像処理周りなど，多くの標準ライブラリが共通のものであるため，ロジック部分をある程度同じ感じで書けます．
- リソースが多い:現在は OSX の情報よりも iOS の情報のほうが圧倒的に Web 上には多いです．このため， Google 検索などである機能を調べた場合， iOS に関するリソースが多いです．これらを活用するには，多少の iOS の知識が必要です．また，初心者向けの参考書なども iOS の方が多いです．
- 開発環境が共通: Xcode は iOS と OSX の両方を開発できますが，これ自体修得するのが大変です．しかし， iOS で慣れておけば OSX でも同じように使えます．

私の事例では，もともと iOS プログラミングを一時期本業にする程度の経験があり，ある日個人的にオープンソースの OSX アプリをカスタマイズする必要があったため挑戦してみたら，思った以上に簡単でした．もちろん， UI 周りなどは学ばないといけないのですが， iOS の方が強い地盤になっていた印象です．

Answer (score 1):

Objective-Cについては明るい方でしょうか？

https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/ObjCTutorial.pdf
Cocoaアプリケーションチュートリアル

古いドキュメントなので、現在の最新のXcodeと見た目や使い勝手に違いがあり、お勧めして良いものかどうかは分かりませんが、Cocoaアプリ制作の基本的な流れは一環として変わっていないので、参考になるかもしれません。現在Interface BuilderはXcodeと統合しているので、XcodeでNibファイルを開いて、編集することが出来ます。

Answer (score 1):

スタンフォード大学のcs193pというコースがお勧めです。iTunes U で無料でビデオ、スライドが視聴できます。とても明確で分かりやすい説明です。私はほぼこれで独学しました。iOSのコースですが、MVCモデルの説明、Objective-CやXcodeの解説部分は良い参考になると思います。

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

ps.
昔、漢字Talk作ってました、懐かしい。System7の頃ね。 :-)